# Pass a variable to a psexec powershell command in vbscript

Tags: powershell, command-line, vbscript, psexec

I'm trying to pass the user input computer name to the psexec command. I've tried about everything. I know the command works because if I run the file by manually entering the computer name is successful. I need to get the strComputer variable into the \strComputer psexec command. Thanks in advance.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.shell")

Dim strComputer

strComputer=InputBox("Run app on remote computer",,"Type name here & click OK")

objShell.run("powershell psexec.exe -i -s \\strComputer \\domain.com\folder\app.exe domain.com")

MsgBox("Scan complete")
```

Comment: Why on earth are you mixing Vbs *and* Powershell with Cli tools?

Comment: I guess because I'm not experienced with this. What would be the best solution to perform a psexec on a remote machine? I couldn't even get the psexec to run until I added the powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a PowerShell script for this?

```
Contents of myscript.ps1
------------------------
$computerName = Read-Host "Enter name of remote computer"
psexec \\$computerName -i -s \\domain.com\folder\app.exe domain.com
"Scan complete"
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I tried to run that, but I don't think GP will allow it. I just get some red text and the PS window disappears. For some reason it will run if I use the way I have it in the original posting.

Comment: @Kevin_A Is this a logon script?  Also, when you run this using powershell.exe you may need to use the parameter `-ExeuctionPolicy Unrestricted`.

Comment: No, not a logon script. I just want to run a LAN monitoring app we use on a remote machine manually. I can run it like I typed above by just entering the actual computer name instead of \\computerName. I don't understand. The Get-ExecutionPolicy returns Restricted, but I can't change it. I read the page at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx and tried to change the policy, but I am not allowed to alter the reg key. I don't understand how it can run with the powershell command within the objShell.run() method. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Just an error saying that the exectution of scripts is disabled on this system, yet I can run the powershell through the .vbs file...

Comment: In the VBS file you aren't technically running a PowerShell script i.e. a .ps1 file.  Even though execution policy is set to restricted, the user can still execute commands interactively in a PowerShell console.  Your VBS script is more or less operating in that mode.  When you run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` make sure you're running that from an elevated/admin console.

Comment: Thanks @Keith. I was able to set execution policy with run as admin. I'll just use the powershell script. Thanks.